# how do i get old value and new value from audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, unpivot

Hi am working on audit data, I have the following data in a table.

```
colm1  colm2   colm3  

f1      50     4/5/2017 3.38

f1      70     4/5/2017 3.40

f1      80     5/5/2017 3.40

f1      30     5/5/2017 5.40
```

I would like to show when and what was changed in a table
    desired output

```
colm1   oldvalue  newvalue  date 

f1      50         70       4/5/2017

f1      70         80       5/5/2017

f1      80         30       5/5/2017
```

Comment: How are the changes made? Through a front end or by update statements in SQL?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. The solution will perhaps be product specific.

Comment: @Chendur its an audit table,changes are made by triggering insert or update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `lag()`:

```
select a.colm1, a.colm2 as newvalue,
       lag(colm2) over (partition by colm1 order by colm3) as prevvalue,
       colum3
from audit a;
```

If you want only three rows:

```
select a.*
from (select a.colm1, a.colm2 as newvalue,
             lag(colm2) over (partition by colm1 order by colm3) as prevvalue,
             colum3
      from audit a
     ) a
where prevvalue is not null;
```

Comment: what if i want to lag more that one column? lets say i have column4 i want both values for colm2 and colm4

Comment: @AvuthuBhargavaReddy . . . Then you would add more `lag()` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(colm1 ,colm2,colm3)
AS
(
SELECT 'f1', 50 ,'4/5/2017 3.38'    Union all
SELECT 'f1', 70 ,'4/5/2017 3.40'    Union all
SELECT 'f1', 80 ,'5/5/2017 3.40' Union all
SELECT 'f1', 30 ,'5/5/2017 5.40'
)
SELECT colm1,Val AS OldValue,colm2 AS newvalue,colm3 From
(
SELECT colm1 ,colm2,LAG(colm2)OVER( order by colm3 )Val,LEFT(colm3,8)colm3 from cte 
)dt
WHERE dt.Val iS NOT NULL
```

OutPut

```
colm1   OldValue    newvalue    colm3
----------------------------------------
f1      50           70         4/5/2017
f1      70           80         5/5/2017
f1      80           30         5/5/2017
```

Comment: @AvuthuBhargavaReddy it's fine as long as it solved  your requirement!

Comment: what if i want to lag more that one column? lets say i have column4 i want both values for colm2 and colm4