# How do I get old value and new values from audit table for all columns

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring boot, Spring JPA, and @auditable in order to maintain the audit logs in tables.
This is the duplicate question of - [how do i get old value and new value from audit table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780063/how-do-i-get-old-value-and-new-value-from-audit-table).
Solution mentioned in the above question is working fo single column.

How we can get old and new values for the all columns ?

eg. current data

```
colm1  colm2   colm3           col4
f1      50     4/5/2017 3.38   33
f1      70     4/5/2017 3.40   33
f1      80     5/5/2017 3.40   44
f1      30     5/5/2017 5.40   55
```

Expected data

```
col_name    colm1   oldvalue  newvalue  date 
col2         f1      50         70       4/5/2017
col2         f1      70         80       5/5/2017
col4         f1      33         44       5/5/2017
col2         f1      80         30       5/5/2017
col4         f1      44         55       5/5/2017
```

first column should indicate the column name whose old and new value we are showing.
I need the old and new values of the all columns from 1st table.

Comment: yea, but can't you add more lag() expressions ? check the comments under accepted answer from link you provided.

Comment: Thanks @Boorsuk i not observed that comment. But yes adding more lag we can do the same. Thanks again